# UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib")

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

Hi I am new to programming, I am currently reading AutomateTheBoringStuff and I come across this error while web scraping `UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib").`

It a simple web scraping program that open the first 5 website link of the word that I writted in my input program.

my code:

```
import webbrowser, requests, bs4

ans = input()
print('Googling...') # display text while downloading the Google page
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + ans)
res.raise_for_status()

# Retrieve top search result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

# Open a browser tab for each result.
linkElems = soup.select('.r a')


# Open a browser tab for each result.
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

When I write html.parser on this line : `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")` The error is no longer here but the program doesn't open my web tab. So I guess it not the right way to resolve this
Thanks for helping!

Comment: it is not error but only warning. `BeautifulSoup` can use different parsers `html5lib`, `html.parser`, `lxml` and they may work in different way (especailly when HTML is incorrect) and sometimes one can see elements but other may not see them.  Other problem can be Google which doesn't like bots/scripts and has big money to block them. You could also use `print()` to see what you get in variable - maybe you don't get any link so there is nothing to open in browser.

Comment: When I write ```print(linkElems)``` it print ```[]``` ... it is no longer possible to make a google scrypt?

Comment: Google can recognize script and block it (because script doesn't click in ads and Google doesn't get money). Better try with other pages.

Comment: @furas ok thank you

Comment: but if you want to try with Google then first try to set correct header `User-Agent` ie. `Mozilla/5.0` or even longer because `requests` uses `Python/xxx`. Next you can try with proxy servers to have different IP in every request.

Comment: some portals offers special proxy servers only to get data from Google. Probably nobody offers special proxy servers for other portals

Comment: BTW: try [http://toscrape.com/](http://toscrape.com/)